# How do Image format on responsive website

Tags: html, css, sass, screen, srcset

Hi My English is quite poor :) sorry for that :)
I design a responsive website. What is the difference between the given files? I don't understand how to adjust them to the screen size.

```
jk_ar_16_9,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_720.jpg
jk_1_s6zmfh_c_scale,w_480.jpg
```

Comment: You may be looking for [<picture>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

Comment: @Fico could you yourself answer any question with only that **little and unclear info**?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that first image is bigger, than the second one. To adjust images to the screen size, use picture tag(learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)):

```
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(min-width:720px)" 
    srcset="jk_ar_16_9,c_fill,g_auto__c_scale,w_720.jpg">
  <source 
    media="(max-width:720px)" 
    srcset="jk_1_s6zmfh_c_scale,w_480.jpg">
  <img 
     src="jk_1_s6zmfh_c_scale,w_480.jpg"
     style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```